# Simple modules are quasi-injective and quasi-projective.

Tags: abstract-algebra, ring-theory, modules, homological-algebra

We say that an $R$-modules $M$ is *quasi-injective* if for every linear monomorphism $f: N \to M$ and every linear morphism $g: N \to M$ there is $h \in End_{R}(M)$ such that $g=hf$. This can be depicted as the following commutativity diagram:

\begin{array}{lll} 0  \rightarrow & N \xrightarrow{f}  & M \\ & \downarrow{g} & \swarrow{h} \\ & M  & \end{array}

In the same fashion we can define a *quasi-projective* $R-$ module. I want to prove that if $M$ is a simple module, then $M$ is quasi-injective and quasi-projective. Here goes my attempt in order to prove the statement just mentioned.

If $M$ is a simple $R$ module, its only submodules are $0$ and $M$ itself. So we can regard the morphism $f$ in the definition of a quasi-injective modules as an inclusion of a submodules $N$ of $M$ into  $M$. But since $M$ its simple we got two cases. First case, $N=0$, so $f$ and $g$ are zero morphism, that is $f=0=g$, so it yields $h$ can be any morphism in $End(M)$. Second case, $N=M$, so it yields that $f,g \in End_{R}(M)$. But Im run out of ideas in finding the appropiate $h \in End_{R}(M)$ such that $hf=g$. Its my guess that its analogue to prove the fact $M$ is quasi projective? Its my approach to the problem right? How does I finish the proof? Thanks.

Comment: So, $f$ is assumed to be *injective*, isn't it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Every nonzero endomorphism of $M$ is actually an automorphism: injective because its kernel is not $M$ hence $0$, and surjective because its image is not $0$ hence $M$.

We don't necessarily get strict equality $N=M$ if $N\ne 0$ but an isomorphism $N\cong M$ only, namely $f$ itself (it's also surjective because of the same reason as above).

Now if $g=0$, take $h=0$.
Otherwise define $h:=g\circ f^{-1}$.

Comment: Thanks! I forgot to see the Schur Lemma here, but yes its right, hands down. Also the same idea works in order to prove that $M$ is also quasi-projective.